# Deploy nestJS websocket feature in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, nestjs

I have a NestJS application used only as a REST API hosted in AWS API Gateway, but I will like to implement a new feature wish is basically build with NestJS web sockets feature but I don't know how to deploy this in AWS. Is there a way to have the NestJS web socket feature in AWS?

PD.
I'm a complete AWS noob :(